# How to get Original Request uri after apache redirection

Tags: java

Is it possible to get the original request uri after apache proxy the url in java code?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the HTTP headers of your request [1] headers like X-Forwarded-For may contain the IP address of the client, X-Forwarded-Host (The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header), X-Forwarded-Server (The hostname of the proxy server). For more detailed explanation see mod_proxy documentation [1].

[1] http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html